# sed regex replace capture group not interpolating

Tags: bash, sed

I'm attempting to use `sed` to replace nanoseconds in a timestamp:

`sed  -r "s/(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g"`

Example:

```
echo "2019-07-15 19:12:26.327801+00" | sed  -r "s/(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g"
```

Locally on my machine this works, and produces `2019-07-15 19:12:26.327+00` as an output. However when I run this elsewhere I get `2019-07-15 1+00` as an output. It seems like my capture group 1 isn't interpolating.

Any advice on how I can fix this?

```
sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. But I suggest using single quotes instead of double quotes, as backslash has no special meaning in single quotes.

Comment: What do you mean *elsewhere*? Which OS? Which shell? What version of sed?

Comment: I'll bet you're using a different shell where it fails, and `\1` is turning into just `1`.

Comment: When I say interpolating, I mean that `1` is being interpreted as replace the capture group with the number 1, not the capture group. Does that make sense? I'm testing on amazon linux GNU sed version 4.2.1. The issue is occurring on a different ec2, same sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: What's the output of `echo "\1"`?

Comment: Sorry @BenjaminW. How exactly would I echo that from `sed  -r "s/(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g"`?

Comment: Just for testing. He is proposing an experiment for you to do by entering directly, not via sed.

Comment: I fixed this by escaping the `\1` with `\\1`. Final command is `sed -r -e 's/\(\([0-9]\{2\}:\)\{2\}[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]*/\\1/g'` but I don't understand why this behavior is changing depending on where it's executed.

Comment: It depends on how your shell interprets backslash escapes in double quoted strings, hence my suggestion to try `echo "\1"` in that shell. Bash would print `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

See [*Treatment of backslashes across shells*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70459/):

> just replace each `\` by `\\` to tell the shell "that it a literall `\` I want"

You need to escape backslash as it acts as escape char in double quotes, for example for a `$` char that signals an interpolated var.